# Issue while reading property file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have the below shell script. Please help me to understand why the values of $mft_dir and $mft_dir1 are different?

**SCRIPT(test.sh)**

```
#! /bin/sh

######## Reading properties file
function getProperty {
    awk -F'=' -v k="$1" '$1==k&&sub(/^[^=]*=/,"")' $ENVIRONMENTROOT/properties/ExtServerConnection.properties
}

key=$2  
######################## LOCAL Server Details ##########################
########MFT path
mft_dir=$(getProperty "${key}_mft_dir")  
mft_dir1="/sjcqa01/exec/ENVIRONMENTROOT/EAIDATA/Inbound/MFT/EXL"    
echo $mft_dir  
echo $mft_dir1

if [ "$mft_dir" != "$mft_dir1" ] ; then  
    echo "Not equal"  
fi  
echo "------------------ END OF THE SCRIPT ---------------------"
```

**Properties File Entry**

```
XYZ_mft_dir=/sjcqa01/exec/ENVIRONMENTROOT/EAIDATA/Inbound/MFT/EXL
```

**Execution Command**

```
./test.sh -key XYZ
```

**Output**

```
/Inbound/MFT
/Inbound/MFT 
Not equal
```

Comment: add some guard chars on your debug output, ie . `echo mft_dir="|$mft_dir|"`. Good luck.

Comment: Check your properties file for carriage returns

Comment: Thanks "that other guy". It was a carriage return issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following sed command to strip off the carriage return and my issue got resolved:

```
sed -e 's/\r//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `#! /bin/sh` line with `#!/bin/bash`.
I did that with your code and it worked perfectly.

```
./so.bash -key XYZ
>>/sjcqa01/exec/ENVIRONMENTROOT/EAIDATA/Inbound/MFT/EXL<<
>>/sjcqa01/exec/ENVIRONMENTROOT/EAIDATA/Inbound/MFT/EXL<<
------------------ END OF THE SCRIPT ---------------------
```

Note I added `>>` and `<<` characters to see the exact output of the echo commands.

Note2: some systems might require `#!/usr/bin/bash`.  Adjust according to your system (`which bash` will show you where it is).

Note3: do not put a space between `#!` and your shell path.

Note4: well done using `$()` and not backticks :-)

Comment: I replaced #! /bin/sh line with #!/bin/bash, but no luck for me.

Comment: Show me.  What I did for testing: **1** copy-paste your code on my Linux, called it so.bash, put `#!/bin/bash`.  **2** copy-paste your properties file entry and put it in a file named ExtServerConnection.properties (Note I modified the path in the script for my test). **3** ran it and got the result above.  **4** What result did you get?  Show as much detail as possible, "no luck" does not help me help you.

Comment: I followed the same steps mentioned by you, but still it is not recognizing both strings as same and "Not Equal" is getting printed. Nevertheless, I used sed command to strip out the carriage return if any and it worked. Thanks for your time!

Comment: ah ok, I copied the entries directly in Linux editor, so no carriage return issue like if you copy from DOS.  Look at `dos2unix` for this.